# PowerApps Do until doesn't work: only first loop works

Tags: power-automate

Do until doesn't work properly when you use **less than or equal to**, It's run only the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **equal to** condition it works properly as per requirement. But when I use **less than or equal to** condition it is not working as per requirement.